# Cannot set focus to textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, focus, highlight

I am using VB and trying to select a portion of the text in a textbox of a separate form. However, I can't seem to find a good way to access the textbox from the other form, although the textbox is public (I am new to VB).

Currently, I'm trying to do this by calling a function located in the form (the form with the textbox), and then focusing on the textbox and selecting/highlighting the text. But it still doesn't work:

```
    Public Sub GetFindLoc(ByVal lngStart As Long, ByVal intLen As Integer)
        frmFind.Hide()
        MessageBox.Show(ActiveForm.Name)
        MessageBox.Show(txtNotes.CanFocus())
        txtNotes.Focus()
        txtNotes.Select(lngStart, intLen)
        frmFind.Show()
    End Sub
```

With this, I first hide the original form, and then try to select the text, and bring back the form. It shows that the active form is the one which I'm trying to select the text on, but it returns false on CanFocus().

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. This was more fiddly than I thought. You need to pass a reference to the other form:

Main form:

```
Public Class frmNotes
  'This is the main form
  'This form has a textbox named txtNotes and a button called btnShowFind
  'txtNotes has .MultiLine=True

  Private mfrmFind As frmFind
  Private Sub btnShowFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowFind.Click
    If mfrmFind Is Nothing OrElse mfrmFind.IsDisposed Then
      mfrmFind = New frmFind(Me)
      mfrmFind.Show()
    Else
      mfrmFind.BringToFront()
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Finder form:

```
Public Class frmFind
  'This form has a textbox called txtFind and a button called btnFind
  Private mfrmParent As frmNotes
  Sub New(parent As frmNotes)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    mfrmParent = parent
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
    If txtFind.Text = "" Then
      MsgBox("Please enter text to find", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
      Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim intSearchBegin As Integer = mfrmParent.txtNotes.SelectionStart + 1
    Dim intStart As Integer = mfrmParent.txtNotes.Text.IndexOf(txtFind.Text, intSearchBegin)
    If intStart > -1 Then
      mfrmParent.txtNotes.Select(intStart, txtFind.Text.Length)
      mfrmParent.txtNotes.Focus()
      mfrmParent.BringToFront()
    Else
      mfrmParent.txtNotes.Select(0, 0)
      MsgBox("No more matches")
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is still returning False on CanFocus() and not highlighting -- Visual Studio made me change the frmNotes to Me though, since this function is declared in frmNotes.

Comment: You are correct, my original answer did not work. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! Is the key point here making frmNotes "parent" in frmFind or is there something I missed?

Comment: A `Class` is the definition of an `Object`. An `Object` is a run-time instance of a `Class`. The `Class` is the cookie-cutter, the `Object` is the Cookie.

VB simplifies things for `Control`s by allowing you to refer to the Object by the Class name (This is what the `GenerateMember` property is about). 

I'm thought you could refer to `Form` Objects using their Class names, but it looks like you can't any more. So here we need to be explicit and hand a reference to the parent form, rather than just using its Class name.

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification!

Comment: No worries. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class frmFind

    Private Sub btnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click

        Dim search As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim
        Dim pos As Integer = frmNotes.txtNotes.Text.IndexOf(search)

        If pos > 0 Then
            frmNotes.txtNotes.Focus()
            frmNotes.txtNotes.Select(pos, search.Length)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is just a "find" form with 1 textbox and 1 button which will highlight the first occurrence of the string in TextBox1 that it finds in txtNotes on the other form. If you want it to find whitespace as well, then remove the `Trim` function. You can add code to find other occurrences or go forward/backward.

Comment: I've tried this approach but nothing happens, it's still not highlighting on the other form. CanSelect() and CanFocus() are both False

Comment: You'll note `CanSelect` and `CanFocus` have nothing to do with my solution, nor are they needed. From the original frmNotes (ie, main Notepad form), you simply call `frmFind.Show()`, the code for that form I show above though I see my edit messed up the top of it so I will fix that now. Add TextBox1 and btnFind.

Comment: In fact the only code on fmrNotes was `frmFind.Show()` that I had in a button click event for simplicity. You would have it in a menu strip or hotkey combination most likely.